# ScrollView is not scrolling react-native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

For some reason my scroll view is not working in my emulator. The Feedcards are being rendered but they are not scrolling. When I surround the FeedCards with `<List>` they go from vertical center to at the top of the screen, so it is doing something. Just not allowing for scrolling.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import FeedCard from '../components/FeedCards/FeedCard';

const Root = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  justifyContent: center;
  backgroundColor: #f2f2f2;
  paddingTop: 5;
`;

const List = styled.ScrollView`
  flex: 1;
`;

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  state = { }
  render() {
    return (
    <Root>
        <List>
          <FeedCard />
          <FeedCard />
        </List>
    </Root>
    );
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's up?

ScrollView only works if the number of rendered elements pass into the device width/height. If you is using an Ios emulator, the scroll should be unlocked, but in Android emulator, just with pass the size